# Find index of element in vector of pairs

Tags: c++, vector, indexing

As stated in the title, I'm trying to find the index of an element in a vector of pairs. I have the following vector: `std::vector<std::pair<std::string, double>> dict`.
The content of my dict is:

```
Name1 11
Name2 9
Name3 10
Name4 12
Name5 13
```

All I have in order to find the index is the `first` attribute of the `pair`. For example I have `Name5` and I would like to find 4. (Since `Name5` is the fifth element).
Does anyone have an idea how to do it ?
I tried something but it doesn't seem to work:

```
auto it = std::find(dict.begin(), dict.end(), movieName);
```

where `movieName` is an `std::string` with `"Name5"` inside.
Thank you!

Comment: you need to use [`std::distance()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would simply go with a normal for_each loop.

So:

```
int index = 0;
for(const auto& pair : dict) {
    if(pair.first == <whatever>) {
        break;
    }
    index++;
}

//if index == dict.size() then print element not found
```

Other way would be using std::find_if() ( Thanks @Tony Delroy :) )

```
auto index = std::distance(dict.begin(), std::find_if(dict.begin(), dict.end(), [&](const auto& pair) { return pair.first == movieName; }));
```

Comment: I've never been a fan of overly forced use of standard algorithms.  If you had to spend 10 minutes on cppreference.com to work out how to do it, instead of 10 seconds writing a loop, it's probably everyone else trying to understand, maintain or evolve your code will too.  Simplicity for the win!

Answer (score 6):

You can use a predicate to decide which entries in the vector should match.  It's easiest to do that with a lambda:

```
auto it = std::find_if(dict.begin(), dict.end(),
              [&](const auto& pair) { return pair.first == movieName; });
```

After you have the iterator, compare it to `dict.end()` to see if there was any match, and if there's a match you can convert it to an index into the vector using std::distance(), as d4rk4ng31 commented under the question.

Comment: error: 'auto' not allowed in lambda parameter in Qt Creator

Comment: @NaturalDemon: such use of `auto` in lambdas was introduced with C++14 - may need to add flags to specify the language version you want to compile with, and/or upgrade your compiler.

Comment: (if you can't be bothered using C++14, you can still hardcode the type - just replace `auto` with `std::pair<std::string, double>`).

Comment: thnx, form mentioning that it works in C14, i used std::pair<std:: ..., ...>) at the moment i wrote my comment.